# Pacman transaction error

Tags: raspberry-pi, arm, archlinux, pacman-package-manager

Today I installed Arch Linux onto my Raspberry Pi and as one of my first steps I tried to install some new packages. However, I always get the same error if I try to install a package:

```
error: failed to commit transaction (wrong or NULL argument passed)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

I checked some other repository servers, but it still does not work. Here is my current mirrorlist:

```
#
# Arch Linux ARM repository mirrorlist
# Generated on 2013-06-13
#

## Geo-IP based mirror selection and load balancing
# Server = http://mirror.archlinuxarm.org/armv6h/$repo

## Berlin
Server = http://de.mirror.archlinuxarm.org/armv6h/$repo
```

Then I tried to clear my cache:

```
pacman -Sc
rm /var/cache/pacman/pkg/*.part
pacman -Syyu
```

It did not work! Any ideas?

Comment: The error occurred because of a network problem.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure your system is up-to-date with "sudo pacman -Syu" Then you can try selecting new mirrors and "sudo pacman -Syy" to refresh your mirrorlist. It's good to have a main mirror, and a few backups.

Try checking the wiki:
[Mirrors - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/mirrors)

Also check Mirrors status page:
[Mirror Status](https://www.archlinux.de/?page=MirrorStatus)

Just as a side note, I couldn't find your mirror in the list of current mirrors, so there could be your problem.

If all else fails, I'd take it to the arch forums, but just a warning, you're going to have to provide a lot more information, packages you're trying to install, and possible the pacman jorunal error messages, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your terminal

> sudo pacman-mirrors --country all --api --protocols all --set-branch stable && sudo pacman -Syyu